# In Swing, is there a property to set a JList disabled foreground color?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

In Swing, is there a property to set a JList disabled foreground color?

I'm using the Netbeans GUI builder and I want to add a property to the resource properties file that sets the color of the text in a JList to a different default when the JList is disabled.  Using the Nimbus LAF, there is a different color for this because the text is gray when disabled but black when enabled.  I just don't want it to be grey when disabled.

The standard foreground color is just .foreground.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DefaultListCellRenderer` extends `JLabel`.  In its `getListRendererComponent` method, it sets its enabled state based on that of the `JList` that is passed in.

The code for painting disabled `JLabel` text in `BasicLabelUI` does some work to paint the text with a shadow effect.  In many subclasses, you will find code that looks for the `"Label.disabledForeground"` UI property. [The Nimbus defaults](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html) seem to look for `"Label.disabledText"`.

You have a couple options:

1. You can set the `"Label.disabledText"` property in the `UIManager`, which will make all `JLabel` instances *and subclasses* that are disabled to take on this coloring.
2. You can create a custom renderer for your `JList` that tests the enabled state of the `JList` and then does whatever custom code that you would like - or omit the enabled state test entirely if you want it to look the same regardless of its enabled state.

I would suggest that you take the custom renderer approach, as it is difficult to say where the change of a `JLabel` property will show up, as that class is used as a builing block in many different components.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I forgot about renderers.  Ended up extending DefaultListCellRenderer, overriding getListRendererComponent, calling super getListRendererComponent and before returning, calling setEnabled(true).  That does exactly what I really wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a property to set then the [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) program should show you the property to change. I don't see a property for the Metal or Windows LAF so it may indicate this is controlled directly in the UI code.